# How to use dapper query SPROC expecting UDT?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, dapper, user-defined-types

not sure how to go about doing this via Dapper but I have a custom type like so:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udtCustomerIds] AS TABLE
(
    [CustomerId] int
)
```

Then have a sproc expecting this to be passed in as a parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetCustomerByCustomerIDs]
    @udtCustomerIds udtCustomerIds READONLY
AS
SELECT [CustomerId] FROM [Customer] C INNER JOIN C.CustomerId = udtCustomerIds.CustomerId
```

My C# code looks like this:

```
var ids = new int[] { 3530, 3567, 21852, 41745 };
var x = connection.Query<List<int>>("dbo.uspGetCustomerByCustomerIDs", new { CustomerIds = ids }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Any ideas what's wrong with it? How do I use Dapper, passing a UDT to a sproc?

Get the error:

> Procedure or function **uspGetCustomerByCustomerIDs** has too many arguments specified.